# How to speed up bash random name generation?

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, performance

i have problem with my code performance. It is running very slow. I need to generate million+ random persons for my postgres db and insert them into db. Person has parameters name,birthdate,gender,age. I created lists for first names and last names from which i am randomly selecting name. Can someone help me? 
Here is my code:

```sh
#docker params
name="`docker ps | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev | grep -v NAMES`"
dbs_name="DBS_projekt"

#load names from files
firstName=(`cat generatorSource/firstNames.txt`)
firstNameCount="`wc -l generatorSource/firstNames.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2`"
secondName=(`cat generatorSource/lastNames.txt`)
secondNameCount="`wc -l generatorSource/lastNames.txt| tr -s ' '  | cut -d ' ' -f2`"

#gender array
gender=("Male" "Female" "Other")

#actual date
now=$(date | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev)
array=()

for ((x = 1; x <= 1000;x++))
do
 array+="INSERT INTO persons(name,birthdate,gender,age) VALUES"
 for (( n=1; n<=1000; n++ ))
 do
    secondrand=$(( ( RANDOM % $secondNameCount )   ))
    firstrand=$(( ( RANDOM % $firstNameCount )   ))
    genderand=$(( ( RANDOM % 3 )   ))
    year=$(( ( RANDOM % 118 ) + 1900  ))
    month=$(((RANDOM % 12) + 1))
    day=$(((RANDOM % 28) + 1))
    age=$(expr $now - $year)
    if [ $n -eq 1000 ]; then
           array+="('${firstName[$firstrand]} 
           ${secondName[$secondrand]}','$year-$month-$day', 
           '${gender[$genderand]}','$age');"
        else
           array+="('${firstName[$firstrand]} 
           ${secondName[$secondrand]}','$year-$month-$day', 
          '${gender[$genderand]}','$age'),"
        fi
 done

done

#run psql in docker and run insert commands
docker exec -i $name psql -U postgres << EOF
\c $dbs_name

$array

EOF
```

Comment: Which is the slow bit?

Comment: It's probably faster if you do it with plain SQL

Comment: Or use python, perl or similar (some language that is fast at string-building) if you don't want to put the _generator_-files into the docker or make them readable from it by other means.

Comment: bash is slow. If you need performance, use another language.

Comment: generate 100k persons and insert them into db takes 12 minutes. :S so i was looking for performance boost for this code

Answer (score 0):

Note that you declare "array" as an array, but you *use* it as a string.

```
array=()
...
 array+="INSERT INTO persons(name,birthdate,gender,age) VALUES"
```

This is what's happening:

```
$ array=()
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='()'
$ array+="first"
$ array+="second"
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="firstsecond")'
```

To insert an element into an array, you must use parentheses:

```
$ array=()
$ array+=("first")
$ array+=("second")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="first" [1]="second")'
```

I suspect this may be one source of slowness: you're constructing one gigantic string. Add the parentheses as shown, and then change the docker call to

```
IFS=$'\n'
docker exec -i $name psql -U postgres << EOF
\c $dbs_name

${array[*]}
EOF
```

Comment: thanks, it increased performance. do you have more suggestions how to improve speed?

Comment: You need to do some benchmarking. What takes the most time, building the array, or the docker call?

Comment: building array for sure

Comment: Then try inserting the data every 1000 instead of building all million